# Run ddev containers on port 80, solve port conflict

Tags: ddev

Instead of using ddev share, I want to run ddev applications on a virtual server (Hetzner, Ubuntu installed, pre-installed docker ce).

As docker already reserved port 80:
Is there a way to forward a specific ddev port to the same port listening to docker?

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1650/docker-proxy
```

My ddev test application is configured to port 8080 and is accessible.

The ddev configuration:

```
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
host_webserver_port: "8080"
```

If I change to

```
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
host_webserver_port: "80"
```

I'm (of course) running into

```
Failed to start test: Unable to listen on required ports, port 80 is already in use
```

Can this conflict be solved by forwarding a port (ddev router) or do I need to change the docker port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker itself does not use ports 80 or 443, so you have something else running there (the most common offender is going to be apache). The docs at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/troubleshooting/#webserver-ports-are-already-occupied-by-another-webserver explain how to debug this. Since it says docker-proxy is running there, it probably means that you have a docker container already running and bound to port 80.

Try these things:

- `ddev poweroff` (to make sure all ddev things are stopped)
- `docker ps -a` will show you other containers that may be running
- `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` will stop all running containers.

I think when you do these things you'll find docker not listening any more; now you just have to find out why it was listening.

As you already know, the docs for various kinds of sharing are at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/topics/sharing/ and you may also be interested in the general on-server approaches in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/alternate-uses/#casual-project-webhosting-on-the-internet-including-lets-encrypt

Comment: Thanks. I did not know the documentation of the alternate uses. That is exactly what I need. Indeed I found out what caused the port conflict: Setting both router_http_port and host_webserver_port to 80. I erased host_webserver_port and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

it's a conflict with another (MAMP, XAMPP, WAMP)write the next:

```
ddev stop 
sudo service apache2 stop 
sudo systemctl disable apache2 
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

If the status inactive. Then it's solved.

```
ddev start
```